# Using two parameters on Hyperlink C# Blazor

Tags: html, asp.net, blazor

I would like to use `<a href>` with two parameters to archive the function of the navigation.

For example, going to https://www.google.com/maps with `https://www.google.com` as str1 and `/maps` as str2.

However, error `Syntax error, ',' expected` is shown.

#### View

```
<a href="@(str1)@(str2)"> Go To Google Maps </a>
```

#### Code

```
string str1 = "www.google.com";
string str2 = "/maps";
```

Comment: why dont you [`string.Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-7.0) the two parameter before sending them into view?

Comment: Becoz str1 will be retrieved after ``OnInitialized()`` and str2 will be generated inside the ``Service.cs``. Both str1 and str2 will be eventually loaded into a DataGrid to become an URL. If I join two strings together beforehand, the system would process twice the dataset (1st: Loads records from DB, 2nd: Join strings per record). And I do not want to load str1 in ``Service.cs``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="@(str1+str2)"> Go To Google Maps </a>
```

It works now.

Comment: Or add `string Href => str1 + str2;`  to your code section to keep your HTML cleaner